# Pandas Python update column with another row value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have à dataframe with millions of row.
As example of my dataframe :

```
Col0, Col1, Col2, Col3
Val0, Val1, Nan, Nan
Val0, Nan, Val3, Nan
Val0, Nan, Nan, Val5
```

My desired output is :

```
Col0, Col1, Col2, Col3
Val0, Val1, Val3, Val5
```

I make an iteration request for the desired output but this take hours.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me what the advantage of doing this would be unless your df simply is a list in which there is no realtion between columns, but here is a solution to this:

for this df:

```
 Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3
0     3     5   Nan   Nan
1     3   Nan    12   Nan
2     3   Nan   Nan    17
```

do this

```
pd.concat([testcol[col].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for col in testcol], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

which gives

```
   0     1     2     3
0  3     5    12    17
1  3   Nan   Nan   Nan
2  3   Nan   Nan   Nan
```

Comment: If you drop all but the first row this is the answer. Though pretty pointless using a DataFrame for that, as you rightly pointed out

Comment: Yes. I thought the nan row drop could be left to the asker as it doesn't demand any effort.